# Visual Studio 2008 sometimes won't open .aspx html markup

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Every now and again I encounter a problem where Visual Studio Professional 2008 (SP1) refuses to open an aspx page.  My site is in a Web Application Project.

Double clicking on the aspx page in solution explorer just causes the tree view node with the code behind and .designer.cs to collapse and expand, it's almost as if VS thinks the file is already open, but it's definately not.

I've also tried right-click + View Markup or View Designer but no joy. I also tried unloading/reloading the project in solution explorer but that doesn't solve the problem either, I actually have to close the whole solution then re-open again (which can take a while if there's lots of projects in the solution).

This sometimes happens on just one or two files, others open without any problems. Anyone else seen this and know of any work arounds and cause?

Cheers
Kev

Comment: Haven't ran into that, but did it start happening only after you installed SP1?

Comment: Haven't experienced this one, but I've noticed loads of nasty little things in SP1 - adding items to the toolbox making the UI vanish, CTRL+H not working, building then the debug session ending intstantly etc...

Comment: I can't actually recall if this ever happened in VS2008 RTM. It happens infrequently but often enough to be annoying as you can imagine.

Comment: I ran into this today and even closing the solution didn't work. I had to completely restart VS to be able to open that page.

Comment: Yep it's a weird one. Hasn't happened since I posted, that's how infrequent it can be. But when it does happen it's usually when you're under time pressures where restarting VS and re-opening that monster solution is gonna take a while.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I'm getting that with just one aspx file in a webproj. I can open it with notepad fine, no one else is having a problem with the file on their computer and it just started happening to me today.
I am using SourceSafe if that matters. I tried closing and reopening VS.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any extras/ plugins installed? I've seen problems like this that were fixed by uninstalling DevExpress add-ons

Comment: This hasn't happened for ages now. I've also re-paved the machine since so I think the cause is now lost forever.

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that I did once install DevExpress CodeRush (demo edition) but it got uninstalled because I preferred ReSharper. I don't remember now if it was installed at that time.